# Add a purrr:slowly or sys.sleep in a map

Tags: r, web-scraping, purrr, rvest

I created a function to **scrape** the fbref.com website. Sometimes in this website or in others that I'm trying to **scrape** I receive a timeout error. I read about it and it is suggested to include a sys.sleep between the requisitions or a purrr:slowly. I tried to include inside the map but I could not. How can I include a 10 seconds gap between each requisition inside the map (It would be 7 requisitions and 6 intervals of 10 seconds).
Thanks in advance and if I do not include something please inform me!

```
#packages
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)
library(tm)

#function

funcao_extract <- function(link1,link2){

fbref <- "https://fbref.com/pt/equipes/"
    dados <- fbref %>% 
    map2_chr(rep(link1,7),paste0) %>% 
    map2_chr(seq(from=2014,to=2020),paste0) %>% 
    map2_chr(rep(link2,7),paste0) %>% 
    map(. %>% 
          read_html() %>% 
          html_table() %>% 
          .[[1]] %>%   #select first table
          dplyr::bind_rows()%>%
          janitor::clean_names() %>% 
          slice(-1) %>% 
          select(-21) %>% 
          rename(nome=1,nacionalidade=2,posicao=3,idade=4,jogos=5,inicios=6,minutos=7,minutos_90=8,gol=9,assistencia=10,
                 gol_normal=11,gol_penalti=12,penalti_batido=13,amarelo=14,vermelho=15,gol_90=16,assistencia_90=17,
                 gol_assistencia_90=18,gol_normal_90=19,gol_assistencia_penalti_90=20) %>% 
          as.data.frame() %>% 
          format(scientific=FALSE) %>% 
          mutate_at(.,c(5:15),as.numeric) %>% 
          mutate(nacionalidade = str_extract(nacionalidade, "[A-Z]+")) #only capital letters
    ) %>% #renomear as colunas
    setNames(paste0(rep("Gremio_",7),seq(from=2014,to=2020))) #name lists
  
}

#test with Grêmio

gremio <- funcao_extract("d5ae3703/","/Gremio-Estatisticas")
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a small example

```r
library(tidyverse)

example <- list(data.frame(a=1:10), data.frame(a=11:20))

example %>%
  map_df(~ {Sys.sleep(10) ; 
                      message(Sys.time());.x} %>%
                 summarise(a = sum(a)))
```

Comment: I'm on mobile atm, so I couldn't give a more sophisticated answer, but I hope it's clear. :-)

Comment: It was perfect!
I really appreciate it!
I tried a lot of things and none of them worked. With your answer I could adapt the code and learn more about the map function!

Comment: What does ";" technically mean?

Comment: @AlvaroMorales `;` seperates different function calls. Usally you are using a line break but - since here everything is in a single line - here this is done by a `semicolon`.

Comment: oh I understand. I don't normally see that.